# How to get system DAY (Monday, tue,...) in android?

Tags: android, android-timepicker

How can i get the system Day in android.
Day ie Monday, Tuesday, wednesday etc.
How can i get system time, month, date etc.

Comment: please show some research first what have you done

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
    String dayInString = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
    Log.wtf(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(), dayInString);
```

Result:

```
08-02 04:52:12.360  15393-15393/com.example A/MainActivity:﹕ Sunday
```

This will give you the proper day even by locale. For more information, refer to the documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).